# How to delay when my actionscript 3 code runs?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drag-and-drop, flash-cs6

I am creating a drag and drop game that I followed through a Lynda tut. I kept getting an error for my game that I created because I noticed (after weeks of reviewing the code and having other people look at it to figure out what was wrong) that the tutorial that I followed did everything on frame one but I was making my game start at frame 3. So if I start my game at frame 1, it works perfectly and I wont get these errors:

*This occurs when I test the movie, once I click continue I am able to see the movie -*

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at simpleSpring()[simpleSpring.as:21]
```

*And this occurs when I drag my object -*

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at DragDrop/drop()[DragDrop.as:33]
```

Since I know these errors won't appear unless I begin the game at frame 1, I want to know what code I can place so that I can begin the game at frames that are past the first frame.

**The following is the code for DragDrop.as**

```
    package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class DragDrop extends Sprite
    {
        var origX:Number;
        var origY:Number;
        var target:DisplayObject;

        public function DragDrop()
        {
            // constructor code
            origX = x;
            origY = y;
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
            buttonMode = true;
        }

        function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
            startDrag();
            parent.addChild(this);
        }

        function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
            stopDrag();

            if(hitTestObject(target))
            {
                visible = false;
                target.alpha = 1;
                Object(parent).match();
            }

            x = origX;
            y = origY;
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the simpleSpring.as

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class simpleSpring extends MovieClip
    {
         var dragdrops:Array;


        public function simpleSpring()
        {
            // constructor code
            dragdrops = [ladyone,ladytwo,ladythree,ladyfour,ladyfive,ladysix];
            var currentObject:DragDrop;
            for(var i:uint = 0; i < dragdrops.length; i++)
            {
                currentObject = dragdrops[i];
                currentObject.target = getChildByName(currentObject.name + "_target");


            }
        }

        public function match():void
        {

        }
    }

}
```

I tried adding the code to a actions layer in the game document but that also does not seem to work correctly.

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow. Try to narrow down your problems and post one question for each problem. Remember that StackOverflow is not a forum.

Comment: Can you not just say in your `DragDrop` function something like `if(currentFrame != 3) gotoAndStop(3);`

Comment: To learn some *real* ActionScript, check out Colin Moock's lost ActionScript Weekend.

Comment: what is about `dragdrops = [ladyone,ladytwo,ladythree,ladyfour,ladyfive,ladysix];` I don't found ladyone, ladytwo, etc

Comment: @pier
Sorry I was just trying to let people know at what point I am in so I do not receive similar solutions that I already tried.

Comment: @christianIrwanHadiWicaksana 
Those are the objects that I have in my flash file. That is their instance names. My game is about dragging ladybugs to flowers matching the same color. I made the ladybug object into movie clips and then duplicated them, and name the duplicates will be given instance names of similar to the draggable objects, but just adding a "_target" to them and making the alpha 0. This way if a user drags the object to the correct spot it stays there.

Comment: How about target is that flower. But if it right place, you just remove MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN listener.

Comment: @christianIrwanHadiWicaksana If they place it in the right place this is when this line of code works : 
     `currentObject.target = getChildByName(currentObject.name + "_target");`

Comment: @putvande Sorry I am still kind of a newbie, would that be placed at the top of the function?

Comment: @Rossincita Is my approach went wrong? If can, use my approach, it will reduce final size. Also, user might think to match it with flower, not your hidden clip

Comment: @ChristianIrwanHadiWicaksana Did not seem to work for me. I put a shape on the flower to indicate where to place the draggable objects. Also I solved that issue. I am such a newbie when it comes to publishing things. I noticed I can add multiple swf files when I publish for android. (I know I have to change my code for touch instead of mouse click) This solves my issue of not being able to code at the beginning frame.

Comment: @ChristianIrwanHadiWicaksana
Thanks for helping me trying to figure it out though!

Answer (score 0):

I am such a newbie when it comes to publishing things. I noticed I can add multiple swf files when I publish for android. This solves my issue of not being able to code at the beginning frame. If I have this game in a separate flash file saved in the same folder with the title movie calling to it with actionscript, the code will work and I am able to publish the whole thing as one file. Thanks again for those that tried to help me figure this out!